# specify y-axis label format with each series in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a large number of series that graph to the chart on selection.

Series A = a series of large integers

Series B = a series of small numbers I want to show as percents

When user clicks to graph series B, the y-axis would have labels in percents like 0.23% instead of just 0.23.

I know I could check each time a user clicks and see whether I should call chart.Axis.update, but it would be much cleaner to pass that data in somehow.

Is it possible to specify y-axis label format in the series?

Comment: Why don't you use two `Y` Axes? One for `A` and one for `B` with labels as `percents`. And please create a jsfiddle for us to edit.

Comment: No, you can't set label format for series. Format for labels can be set in yAxis object. Or just use `yAxis.formatter` and there check what should be displayed. It's much cleaner than `Axis.update()` and has much better performance.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! This is actually a simplification of my actual problem. I already do have 2 y-axis, and I add series using addSeries - which doesn't trigger a check for yAxis.formatter. If I were to recreate the chart from scratch everytime I load a new series, the yAxis.formatter trick would work, so I might do that.

Comment: Still, live demo would be great.